# Rails "Ancestry gem" and "Acts-as-taggable-on": "has_children?" method with "tagged_with"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on, ancestry

I'm using **"Ancestry"** and **"Acts as taggable on"** gems.
I want to know how to search if a node of Ancestry have many childrens with some tags.

Let's example (model: Hardware) menu:

```
Father
  -> Children (Here there are many "tablets" for the model hardware) 
  -> Children (Here there are many "smartphone" for the model hardware)
  -> Children (Here there are... and so on...)
  -> Children
        -> ChildrenTwo (Here there are many "mousepad" for the model hardware, ancestry children of the parent)
```

Now, every "product" in every hardware's menu has one or more tags with "Acts as taggable on".

I want to know and write in menu html that there is at least one tag for at least one product in every ancestry level.

If yes, create a children of every ancestry with the name of the tag DISTINCT for every product in that ancestry level.

I know my language is worse. But I think is a great feature, because it's intelligent and dynamic.

For create the menu I'm using this code, that now works only for the ancestry gem, I don't know how to integrate it with acts-as-taggable-on.

```
 <% collection.arrange(:order => :name).each do |category, sub_item| %>
  <li>
    <% if category.has_children? %><%= link_to category.name, '#' %><% else %><%= link_to category.name, category_path(category.name) %><% end %>

    <% if category.has_children? %>
      <ul><%= render partial: "category", locals: { collection: category.children } %></ul>
    <% end %>

  </li>
<% end %>
```